# Make li content not overlap column border

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have html table and in the column of that table I have list content but I have some problem with the list display on column. When the list content is too long the content overlapping border column it happen when I in mobile screen. I want to make it not overlapping the border but I still cannot do it.

This is simple visual of the problem.

[image]

It's display correctly when in desktop browser but when I move into mobile screen I got this.

[image]

This is the code.

```
<table style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>
        <ul style="list-style: none; text-align: left;">
          <li>List Content List Content List Content List Content</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you include some codes?

Comment: Yes, code please. Any reason why you have an inline list in a table?

Comment: @GvM I just do standard code table and ul li

Comment: @NathanielFlick I just do standard code table and ul li

Comment: Why not use `word-wrap: break-word;`?

Comment: @HarikrishnanN I already try that but still doesn't work

Comment: @Antonio show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the problem in your code as it is working just fine

```css
tr td,
tr th {
  border: 1px solid;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>
        <ul style="list-style: none; text-align: left;">
          <li>List Content List Content List Content List ContentList Content List Content List Content List Content v List Content List Content</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually I got this when in mobile screen. I will edit my questions again.

Comment: what did you do to make the mobile screen layout?

Comment: I don't do anything. That's what I want to ask to all of people here what I must to do in mobile screen code ?